# Navigate to new window in Prism WPF

Tags: wpf, prism

**QUESTION 1**

I know there is a way to open popup dialog with custom view using *InteractionRequestTrigger*, *PopupWindowAction* and *InteractionRequest*. But I am looking for solution like registering Window and WindowViewModel for navigation and call *INavigationAsync.Navigate("SomeWindowUri", someParameters)*. It seems much simpler and cleaner solution. Does Prism support such approach?

**QUESTION 2**

I have main window (MainWindow) and new window (NewWindow) to be displayed from MainWindow. I am trying to display some view in region which is defined in NewWindow. When I use IRegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion it works as expected. But when I display NewWndow and then call IRegionManager.RequestNavigate nothing happens. The method IRegionManager.RequestNavigate works as expected when region is in MainWindow. Is it my mistake or Prism cannot do navigation in separate window?

Here is an example: https://bitbucket.org/equo/prismregionnavigationtest.git
It is modified example of Prism example for WPF: 17-BasicRegionNavigation. After opening new window there nothing happens when clicking on any button, but ViewA or ViewB should be displayed below. After uncommenting MainWindow1  in App.CreateShell method the window works as expected.

Comment: The navigation service navigates between views in regions. It doesn't open shell windows.

Comment: OK, so I have to create my own solution for opening windows. What about second question? Is it my mistake or Prism cannot do navigation in separate window?

Comment: It's hard to say what you are doing wrong without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK, so I understand it is my mistake. I will try to fix it on my own and if I will not manage with it I will provide some example.

Comment: @mm8 I have added example. Could check it?

Comment: According question 1: I have just found out that Prism team is working on IDialogService which is doing exactly what I wanted to. https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1682

Comment: According to question 2: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1786 it is possible to use regions in new window. As I do not have pluralsight account I cannot verify the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According question 1:** The Prism team is working on new dialog service which is doing exactly what I want to. https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1682
It is already available via preview version of prism.

**According question 2:** To make it working it is needed to create scoped region and attach it to newly created window.

```
_ScopedRegion = _RegionManager.CreateRegionManager();
RegionManager.SetRegionManager(newWindow, _ScopedRegion);
```

And then use it to navigate in new window.

```
_ScopedRegion.RequestNavigate("NewRegion", "ViewA");
```

The demo is here:
https://bitbucket.org/equo/prismregionnavigationtest.git